# How to give a call to stored procedure added in .edmx file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database

How to give a call to stored procedure added in .edmx file?
I have added one .edmx file in my application.but now i have to give a call to my stored procedure.
procedure is get added as a class.I have created one object of that class and values of parameters are set.
now my question is how i can give call to my stored Procedure?
Please Help....

```
namespace ABC.Controllers
{
    public class ProductSegment_Controller : Controller
    {
        CRUDWithAjax.Models.CountryMaster_Details_Result Rs = new CountryMaster_Details_Result();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Rs.Operaion = "SELECT";
            Rs.Country_Code_int = 0;
            Rs.Country_Name_var = "";

            List<CountryMaster_Details_Result> allCountries = new List<CountryMaster_Details_Result>();
            return View(allCountries);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check this: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/execute-stored-procedure-using-dbcontext.aspx

Comment: Check this out - [How to Call Stored Procedure from Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC](http://yassershaikh.com/how-to-call-stored-procedure-from-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you add a stored proc to your edmx using the add function import option, you should be getting a screen like as shown below. Specify a return type if needed and give a function import a name. This name will later be used to call/run the stored proc.

[image]

And so if all is ok, you should be able to see the function added to your model browser as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

```
using(var context = new SimplePmEntities())
{
    var data = context.Test_EF("yasser", 0);
}
```

Source :  [How to Call Stored Procedure from Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC](http://yassershaikh.com/how-to-call-stored-procedure-from-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc/)